# Remove/ignore white-space or ink from a symbol/it's glyph

Tags: javascript, html, css

This symbol: ▴ (HTML code,  `&#9652;`). Try selecting it, as you'll see, it as every other symbol has whitespace around.

Is there a way to remove this whitespace, so the symbol is simply like if it would've been a drawn image?

I tried using CSS's `clip` property, but didn't work.

Any possible ways with CSS only? Or a way to calculate where actual symbol starts with javascript and then apply with calculation to position this symbol according to it's real borders?

Intended to be used with a fixed font.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What "white space"?  There's no white space around that, other than the areas of the glyph that don't have "ink".  What is it that you're asking?

Comment: Do you want it to have a transparent background... without making it an image?

Comment: Well, those glyph areas that doesn't have ink is the same thing as whitespace. There's nothing. And that's what I want to remove.

Comment: @JasonGennaro, it by default has transparent background..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make its `line-height` smaller than 1, like .5 or something (experiment a bit).

As for the `clip` property, it only works if the element is absolutely positioned.

Answer (score 0):

as it's a symbol, its different depending on the font you're using. the easiest way would be to just search for and choose a font where there's no (or less) whitespace or [play around and try this on your own](http://jsfiddle.net/HuLfm/1/).

**EDIT**:
at least, it might be easier to use an icon, even for such a simple symbol. if you want to keep it simple, thera are [a lot of free B/W icon-sets out there in the www](http://www.codefear.com/graphics/20-free-black-white-icon-sets/).

Comment: It will have fixed font. And by using icons- yes it will work, but you're limited to one or have to change the icon. I want this to be as dynamic as possible, because there are other symbols out there that have white-space/uncolored glyph areas around it and could be used.

Comment: What resolution you're on? - because here on 1920x1080 I have that white block not exactly below the symbol. Plus, those values added to span/.symbol doesn't look very dynamic to me. :P

Comment: ´cause you can't do it in a dynamic way (or better: i absolutely can't think of any way)

Comment: an explanation for the downvote would be really nice. to quote the FAQ: "If you see misinformation, vote it down. Add comments indicating what, specifically, is wrong" (http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette)

Comment: thanks for that, Tom - but someone downvoted without giving any reason. It is a pity.